# Oracle export database with different SID

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, export

I have been using the exp and imp commands in oracle to export and import my databases.

I usually use

```
exp My_DB/MyPass file=dump_My_DB_20130729.dmp

imp My_DB/MyPass file=/tmp/dump_My_DB_20130729.dmp fromuser=My_DB touser=My_DB
```

Where My_DB is hte user/db and MyPass is the password.

My databases have always used SID = orcl

Our infrastructure team have now cloned My_DB database and put in on another SID (orcl2)
The users/databsae name is the same. The SID is the only difference

How can I use the exp and imp to export and import. I found [this link](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORACLE_SID) which describes setting the global sid variable which I presume would update which database I export/import. Ideally I would like a switch on the command so I can dont have to go changing environmental variables.

I cannot see any way of doing this via the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch01.htm) though

Is there an easy way of changing SID for export?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have entries for `orcl` and `orcl2` in your `tnsnames.ora` file?

Comment: hmmm....not sure Im afraid. Let me do a find on the server for that file. I dont know about it as our infrastructure team set up the databases. I want to do back up etc as they are dev dbs

Comment: @AlexPoole found it from this http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsnames.ora. In my file it just has the orcl config. Not the orcl2 configuration

Comment: is it a file you control, or the DBA? You might want to get your infrastructure team to add the `orcl2` equivalent, unless it' your own copy, in which case you can duplicate the `orcl` entry and just change the alias and SID/service name to `orcl2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have entries for the two databases in your `tnsnames.ora` file, you can [specify the TNS alias to use as part of the connection string](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_export.htm#autoId77):

```
exp My_DB/MyPass@orcl2 file=dump_My_DB_20130729.dmp
```

That assumes the alias is set up with the same name as the SID, something like:

```
orcl=
 (DESCRIPTION= 
   (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=my.host)(PORT=1521)) 
   (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)))
orcl2=
 (DESCRIPTION= 
   (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=my.host)(PORT=1521)) 
   (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl2)))
```

If you're doing this on the same machine the database is on then it's likely the DBA has configured this in a global `tnsnames.ora`. If that doesn't exist, or you want to override it, you can create your own file and point the environment variable `TNS_ADMIN` to the directory it is in.

It's also more likely that it will contain the `SERVICE_NAME` in the connect data section, rather than the `SID`, though they could be the same. If you know the service name you can bypass the `tnsnames.ora` file if you prefer:

```
exp My_DB/MyPass@//my.host:1521/<service_name> file=...
```

You should also look at using [datapump](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_overview.htm) (`expdp` and `impdp`) rather than the legacy `exp` and `imp`, since you're on 11g.